# Java Arrays - Do each element in array hold pointer to the next element

Tags: java, arrays, stack

Java LinkedList class uses doubly linked list to store the elements.

Does Arrays in Java use singly-linked list ?

Is this how array and stacks are different in java.

Comment: Even for linked lists, you won't be able to get an object from it that holds a reference to the next object unless you explicitly did that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. An array is just a contiguous block of memory, with a length that can be checked to make sure you don't try to access elements outside the array's bounds.

To get to a specific element, the VM just (logically, at least) takes the start address of the data in the array, and adds the index multiplied by the element size.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet - it's a pleasure to have you (The most reputed user in Stackoverflow) answer my question :) . So how exactly are Stack different from array. I know that stack cannot be accessed randomly as in array. why is it so ?

Comment: @user2048204: Stack is a class, rather than a built in native type like arrays. I suggest you look at the source code of Stack to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

STACK follows LIFO. Thus the item that is first entered would be the last removed.

In array the items can be entered or removed in any order. Basically each member access is done using index. No strict order is to be followed here to remove a particular element.

[see this link](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/37629)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays  are completely  different  from linked list. When it comes to linked list,  complexity to remove item from list is lower  cost compare to remove item from arrays.